# Curly braces inside PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I want to build this JS to a PHP array:

```
title : 'Property',
image : '1-1-thmb.png',
type : 'For Sale',
price : '$price',
address : '$address',
bedrooms : '$bedrooms',
bathrooms : '$maxguests',
area : '$area',
position : {
    lat : $lat,
    lng : $lng
},
markerIcon : 'marker-green.png'
```

I tried normal PHP array with JSON_ENCODE and PRETTY PRINT, but I dont know how to show the 'position' part inside an array.

Could you please help me?

Thanks in advance,

Tibor

Comment: Are you trying to encode it as that? Position will need to be an object. Just add (object) before your array declaration for the position part, or specify that part with an extra line of code eg $data['position'] = (object) $data['position'] then encode as normal

Comment: @scrowler Does it even need to cast as an object? Associative arrays should automatically become JSON object notation shouldn't it?

Comment: Thanks for your aswers so far, i have tried nothing so far, I wrote an array and I stuck at the position part because I dont know how to write that part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP >=5.4

```
[
    'title' => 'Property',
    'image' => '1-1-thmb.png',
    'type' => 'For Sale',
    'price' => '$price',
    'address' => '$address',
    'bedrooms' => '$bedrooms',
    'bathrooms' => '$maxguests',
    'area' => '$area',
    'position' => [
        'lat' => '$lat',
        'lng' => '$lng'
    ],
    'markerIcon' => 'marker-green.png'
]
```

Comment: Think you mean >= 5.4.0

Comment: @JonStirling Yes. Thanks. That's the last version of PHP I used and I wasn't sure when the square brackets were added. I've corrected my answer according to your suggestion.